# Java read at-most-once map

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there an implementation of java.util.Map that only allows a value to be read once? What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
Map map = new ReadOnceMap();
map.put("key", "value")
System.out.println(map.get("key")); // prints "value"
System.out.println(map.get("key")); // prints null
```

EDIT: requirements:

- existing implementation
- values are guaranteed to be read at most one time

Comment: Extend HashMap and after it is read, just remove it.

Comment: This is an odd question. But why not just remove the item from the map once it's been queried?

Comment: If there is an implementation of this behavior out there, I generally prefer to use that (e.g. in apache commons lang or google guava).

Comment: @James Black, extending HashMap is not always as easy as you think, unless you know the implementation. See "Effective Java" by Bloch (item 14 in my version).

Comment: @three_cups_of_java - My thought is to just extend and then override the get function, while still calling it, but, in actuality I wouldn't worry about having a ReadOnceMap, I delete the key when I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class GetOnceHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> v = new ArrayList<V>(super.values());
        clear();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> e = new HashSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>(super.entrySet());
        clear();
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is along the right lines, but what about Map.values()? In the end, I'm looking for an implementation that I don't have to write or test.

Comment: You are right. Maybe you need to specify more. How about Map.containsValue(), Map.entrySet()? Is that a read? Should the value be remove after that?

Comment: Yes, I could have been more specific. But I'm looking for an existing library. I think I'll have to write this myself since I can't find it on google.

Comment: I'm going to make this as the correct answer since I based my implementation off of it. Not sure about this, since it does not actually answer my questions.

Comment: If you found one please post the link too. I'm also interested.

Answer (score 4):

map.remove() should give you the behaviour you want

```
Map map = new ReadOnceMap();
map.put("key", "value")
System.out.println(map.remove("key")); // prints "value"
System.out.println(map.remove("key")); // prints null
```

Comment: This would work, but I'd like to guarantee that values are only read once. This could easily be subverted use map.get.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the remove() method instead of the get() method. The remove() method returns the object being removed from the map. So, the first time you'll get your object and after that it will return null.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation I came up with.

NOTE: This is not really production-quality because I'm counting on `new ArrayList` and `new HashSet` to eagerly (not lazily) read the values. To make this production quality, I would get rid of inheritance and use a dynamic proxy or object composition.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class ReadOnceMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet = new HashSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(super.entrySet());
        clear();
        return entrySet;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> values = new ArrayList<V>(super.values());
        clear();
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of super.values() and super.entrySet(). It's only create a "view" to the underlying data. After clear() you won't have anything anymore.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I get for not testing code first. This is why object inheritance can be so difficult. I'll update my code shortly.

Comment: I updated my code to create defensive copies for entrySet and values. Note: the defensive copies suffer from the original problem, but I think the implementation of ArrayList and HashSet work this the above implementation.